# Is it possible to use USB Modem in Recovery HD?

Tags: macos, recovery-hd

A quick question here, but is it possible to connect to the internet using a USB Modem in Recovery HD? Or is the only way to connect through WiFi or Ethernet. I haven't seen any clear/obvious ways of connecting but is it in any way possible?

Comment: Does your USB modem require any drivers?

Comment: @Keyboard_Gamer not that i know of. It has send to work oob.